# Clearing AWS 'not authorized' error message

Tags: amazon-web-services, runtime-error, amazon-dynamodb

I am using AWS Mobile Hub for iOS. I am having trouble accessing one of the dynamodb tables (RemoteFileInfos) in my app. The error message I am getting is:

```
2017-06-12 13:19:49.851462-0500 FormValet-R[3659:1789148] Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSServiceErrorDomain Code=6 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=com.amazon.coral.service#AccessDeniedException, Message=User: arn:aws:sts::999999999:assumed-role/[role name]/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:UpdateItem on resource: [dynamodb table ARN]}
```

I don't get this error when writing to the other tables (Users and RemoteShareInfos) in my app.

Here is the "nosqldatabase" policy embedded in the authenticated role ([role name]) mentioned above:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
                "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:ListTables",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:Scan"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:999999999:table/Users",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:999999999:table/Users/*",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:999999999:table/RemoteFileInfos",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:999999999:table/RemotFileInfos/*",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:999999999:table/RemoteShareInfos",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:999999999:table/RemoteShareInfos/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I notice that the third token in my Role ARN is "iam" (i.e. "arn:aws:iam::99999999999…) whereas the Role ARN in the error message has a third token of "sts" (i.e. "arn:aws:sts::99999999999…). Could that be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the `99999999999` is your account number?

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. Just the kind of error I had to look for.

Answer (score 0):

Programmer error. The table name in the error message is not the same as the actual table name. I misspelled the table name in the AWSDynamoDBObjectModel subclass.